# Exposing built in server to outside machine

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, moinmoin

I would like to use moinmoin's built in server (running on ubuntu) to serve pages to other machines on my LAN. With the --interface flag, I can connect to the from the host machine by pointing my browser to `192.168.72.131:8080`, but the server does not respond to queries from outside.

I found [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/MoinMoin/InstallDocs#linuxstandalone-install), but none of the steps seem to work.

`iptables` seems like a good bet, but I don't even know where to start; e.g. do I put it in the `PREROUTING` table, what flags do I use?

How can I enable other machines on my network to access the server?

Answer (score 0):

From the moin perspective, it is usually enough to have the web server listen on the correct interface (maybe also try 0.0.0.0 for "all interfaces").